# Invert direction of game

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am developing a basic game where the user needs to go through the openings and avoid crashing with the obstacles. My issue now is that the flow of the game is from the bottom to the top, when in fact I need the obstacles to come from the top to the bottom.

What am I missing in the code? Any help is appreciated.

```js
let myObstacles = [];

let myGameArea = {
    canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
    frames: 0,
    start: function() {
      this.canvas.width = 700;
      this.canvas.height = 500;
      this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
      this.canvas.classList.add('canvasBg');
      document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
      this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    },
    clear: function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    },
    stop: function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    },
    score: function() {
        var points = Math.floor(this.frames / 5);
        this.context.font = "18px serif";
        this.context.fillStyle = "black";
        this.context.fillText("Score: " + points, 350, 50);
    }
  }


  class Component {
    constructor(width, height, color, x, y) {
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
      this.color = color;
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.speedX = 0;
      this.speedY = 0;
    }
  
    update() {
      let ctx = myGameArea.context;
      ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
      ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }

    newPos() {
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY;
      }

    left() {
        return this.x;
    }
    right() {
        return this.x + this.width;
    }
    top() {
        return this.y;
    }
    bottom() {
        return this.y + this.height;
    }
    
    crashWith(obstacle) {
        return !(
          this.bottom() < obstacle.top() ||
          this.top() > obstacle.bottom() ||
          this.right() < obstacle.left() ||
          this.left() > obstacle.right()
        );
      }
    }
  
    function checkGameOver() {
        let crashed = myObstacles.some(function(obstacle) {
          return player.crashWith(obstacle);
        });
      
        if (crashed) {
          myGameArea.stop();
        }
      }
  

  document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 38: // up arrow
        player.speedY -= 1;
        break;
      case 40: // down arrow
        player.speedY += 1;
        break;
      case 37: // left arrow
        player.speedX -= 1;
        break;
      case 39: // right arrow
        player.speedX += 1;
        break;
    }
  };

  function updateObstacles() {
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i++) {
        myObstacles[i].y += -3;
        myObstacles[i].update();
      }


    myGameArea.frames += 1;
    if (myGameArea.frames % 60 === 0) {
      let x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
      let y = myGameArea.canvas.height;
      let minWidth = 20;
      let maxWidth = 200;
      let width = Math.floor(
        Math.random() * (maxWidth - minWidth + 1) + minWidth
      );
      var minGap = 70;
      var maxGap = 200;
      var gap = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxGap - minGap + 1) + minGap);
      myObstacles.push(new Component(width, 10, "green", 0, y));
      myObstacles.push(
        new Component(y-width-gap, 10, "green", width+gap, y)
      );
    }
  }


  document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    player.speedX = 0;
    player.speedY = 0;
  };

  function updateGameArea() {
    myGameArea.clear();
    player.newPos();
    player.update();
    updateObstacles();
    checkGameOver();
    myGameArea.score();
  };

myGameArea.start();
let player = new Component(30, 30, "red", 0, 110);
```

Comment: Invert your "y" values???

Comment: What part(s) of this code should be handling this?  Where, *in the code*, do things start to behave differently than you expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work by changing 3 things in your `updateObstacles` function.

First, change `myObstacles[i].y += -3` to `myObstacles[i].y += 3`

Second, change `let y = myGameArea.canvas.height` to `let y = 0`

Third, change

```
new Component(y-width-gap, 10, "green", width+gap, y)
```

to

```
new Component(x-width-gap, 10, "green", width+gap, y)
```

Full code:

```
function updateObstacles() {
  for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i++) {
    myObstacles[i].y += 3;
    myObstacles[i].update();
  }


  myGameArea.frames += 1;
  if (myGameArea.frames % 60 === 0) {
    let x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
    let y = 0;
    let minWidth = 20;
    let maxWidth = 200;
    let width = Math.floor(
      Math.random() * (maxWidth - minWidth + 1) + minWidth
    );
    var minGap = 70;
    var maxGap = 200;
    var gap = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxGap - minGap + 1) + minGap);
    myObstacles.push(new Component(width, 10, "green", 0, y));
    myObstacles.push(
      new Component(x-width-gap, 10, "green", width+gap, y)
    );
  }
}
```

[Example jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mr2fcejt/)